# Put and Post request in single useFetch custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to call two functions for fetch(esp wth async await) one for POST and other for GET. Can we do it in a single useEffect hook? So if I have a custom hook or context for this, I can access it depending on the api call. Something like if the api to be called is with GET, I have to call getRequest() and postRequest for POST. I want to call one useCustomeHook for this. Whats the best way to do this. ??

Existing code looks similar to this :

```
function getRequest(url,data){
    return $http({
      method : 'POST',
      url,
      data : JSON.stringify(data),
      cache : false,
      headers : {
        Accept : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'charset' : 'utf-8'
      }
   });
}

function postRequest(url,data){
    return $http({
      method : 'POST',
      url,
      data : JSON.stringify(data),
      cache : false,
      headers : {
        Accept : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'charset' : 'utf-8'
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: May you be more specific with what you want? For me it is really not clear. The only thing I can tell you right away is: there is `Promise.all(iterable)` to combine several promises in to one. so you can combine your two request in to "one" with this.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I am sorry. Its both Post. I just edited it. This how the existing code looks..they are using POST for both request except the name is different. I felt like using a different approach in react.

Comment: ok, just but both the function calls in an `useEffect` hook, whats the problem.